# get details on page load , and shared in controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to get Product data as soon as app is initialized, using the same controller I am using in a different section of the page which creates a different instance.

**HTML:**

```
<header class="clearfix" ng-controller="EntityDetailController"
                   ng-init="entity_id={{id}}; get_details('products');">

...
</header>
```

**JS:**

```
    $scope.result = Products.get({
            type : type,
            id : $scope.entity_id
        });
        $scope.result.$promise.then(function(result) {

      });
```

I need to store data in some service so that later on I can share data with all controllers and I also need to notify all controllers once data has been received so that they can fetch data from factory.

Comment: use it on run phase of the application. Find it about in documents/api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for achieving it:

1. Include the service part inside the .`run` method by injecting service there. So when the service call resolves, the data will be available across all the controllers.

It's much cleaner approach compared to `ng-init`

```
angular.module('yourApp')
 .run(['ProductsService', '$http', function (ProductsService, $http) {
  // make the api request here
}]);
```

2. Use `resolve` property in your `ng-router`. Before the app controller loads, make the service request. So once the service resolves, the controller will load.

By default the service data will be available all the controllers once you inject the service. No need to broadcast it.

Comment: yes i tried loading data in run , but i was not aware to use resolve . can you please share about resolve.Also, m not using ng-route in my application .

Comment: what if data loading takes time in run . if controller will be initiated by that time. how can i update or force it to again load data from factory.